# Cron in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have made an app using Google App Engine in python of weekly Project and assessment report submitting.

I want to check that on Friday who have submitted the report and who don't just send the scheduled notification mail that he haven't submitted the report in last week.

but i don't want to send the notification mail on Monday who have submitted the report in last week, just to those who haven't submitted the report

so please suggest me some idea for that.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to fathom what you want (your English is very hard to parse), but anyway, besides Task Queues which are much more flexible and powerful (and may be harder to use for simple jobs that cron functionality covers perfectly), you can use cron to schedule App Engine tasks in Python by following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but anything you can do with cron can be done via TaskQueues in GAE, so read this http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

`App Engine applications can perform background processing by inserting tasks (modeled as web hooks) into a queue. App Engine will detect the presence of new, ready-to-execute tasks and automatically dispatch them for execution, subject to scheduling criteria.`